# How to force only newer KDE packages to be installed?

Tags: apt, kubuntu, kde, plasma, plasma-5

Running "xenial" release (Ubuntu 16.04) and was curious to install newer KDE Plasma 5.10 from "bionic" release repository.

Added to sources.list:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe multiverse
```

Added the following to `preferences.d` to not allow "bionic" packages to be installed by default on `apt-get dist-upgrade`:

```
Package: **
Pin: release n=bionic*
Pin-Priority: 50
```

How do I upgrade just KDE packages? Running `apt-get install -t bionic plasma-desktop` shows me to update only some packages, not all KDE based.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. You are going to break your system.

Comment: What's terrible in updating just KDE? Why am I required to update to newer Ubuntu e.g. 17.04 to be able to get newer KDE?

Comment: KDE packaged for bionic is written for ubuntu-core 18.04 and only tested for 18.04.  Your ubuntu-core is 16.04 xenial and is thus untested with the newer Qt/KDE environment with all your OS api/abi's being older versions.  I agree with @Bruni .  Yeah it may be good for certain functions, but you'll have to accept it being less stable.  (thankfully Qt varies less than GTK+, but you're still doing something risky...)   If you want the Bionic stuff - why not just run 18.04?

Comment: This https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports should be the way to go if you want newer versions of KDE on Ubuntu. Alternatively, you could have a look at kde neon.

Comment: @Bruni your comment looks like the start of a good answer to me.

Answer (score 3):

In general, it is a bad idea to mix repositories.The KDE packaged for bionic might bring in versions of packages that are incompatible with older Ubuntu versions. Packages will be compiled against libraries available in 18.04 and not necessarily in older versions.

If you want to try newer KDE versions and keep a stable system, you could either install KDE from the [KDE backports](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports) repository or try [KDE neon](https://neon.kde.org/faq) (though the latter is not supported on this site.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install a newer version of KDE it's always best to find packages specifically built for your version, "xenial" (16.04) in your case. These are available in KDE Neon repos.

See [How to install KDE Plasma 5.11 on Ubuntu 16.04 (Kubuntu 16.04)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/993639) question.