# How to install KDE Plasma 5.11 on Ubuntu 16.04 (Kubuntu 16.04)?

Tags: 16.04, kde, plasma

How to install KDE Plasma 5.11 on Ubuntu 16.04 (Kubuntu 16.04)?

It seems to be not possible to be done simply from repositories like highlighted in this question: [How to force only newer KDE packages to be installed?](https://askubuntu.com/q/980363)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add Kubuntu Backports repo:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
   ```
2. Get key for Neon package archive:

   ```
   wget -q -O - http://archive.neon.kde.org/public.key | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
3. Add repo:

   ```
   sudo /usr/bin/add-apt-repository -y -u 'deb http://archive.neon.kde.org/release xenial main'
   ```
4. Install new packages:

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
   ```

   4a. You might encounter [this problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/6yal60/kde_neon_update_breaks_qmlmoduleorgkdepurpose) so follow the workaround provided in the article.

Solution inspired by [this thread](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=249871#p1345918).

Comment: I guess you have tested this and it works. Could you mark this as definitive? Any ideas on Plasma 5.12?

Answer (score 0):

and if you want a complete, up-to-date KDE desktop: after the steps Te Ri mentioned, install the complete desktop with `sudo apt install neon-desktop`